# Please provide a valid WRITE query

Tags: scala, apache-spark, neo4j, minimum-spanning-tree

I try to run minimum spanning tree algorithm inside Spark using Neo4j Connector. But when I try to call it I get an error: Please provide a valid WRITE query.
My code looks like this:

```
val df = (1 to 10)/*...*/.toDF()
df.write
  .format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource")
  .option("url", "bolt://localhost:7687")
  .option("query", "CALL gds.alpha.spanningTree.minimum.write('graph', {  startNodeId: id(1), relationshipWeightProperty: 'cost'," +
        "  writeProperty: 'CONNECT',weightWriteProperty: 'writeCost'})")
  .save()
```

Can calling an algorithm can be done inside write function?